# ContourPlot and 3Dplot of $f(x,y,z)=x z + y z - x y z$

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

I have a function of 3 variables:  $x$, $y$, and $z$. This is the function:
$$f(x,y,z)=x z + y z - x y z$$

1. Is there a way for me to graph this function? (3D graph)
2. Can you sketch several representative contour plots from the family of equations for various choices of c. We might place them all together in one plot?
3. Can this function of three variables be visualized as a 2D grid of 2D contours? As shown in the picture [image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You literally named the solution in your title. [`ContourPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot3D.html) [`ContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html). And for the last one you'll also want to look at [`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Grid.html). Perhaps also interesting: [`RegionPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot3D.html)

Comment: "Modify"?... modify *how*?  "[C]hoice of cc"?... what is "cc"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You (apparently) have a scalar function of three variables, so you cannot use a simple `ContourPlot`; you must use `ContourPlot3D`.  Moreover 3DPlot (which does not exist in *Mathematica* but instead `Plot3D`) takes a function of *two* variables and plots the value in the third dimension.

Instead you should use this:

```
DensityPlot3D[x z + y z - x y z, 
          {x, -2, 2}, 
          {y, -2, 2}, 
          {z, -2, 2},
 PlotLegends->Automatic]
```

[image]

If you want contours:

```
ContourPlot3D[x z + y z - x y z, 
          {x, -2, 2}, 
          {y, -2, 2}, 
          {z, -2, 2},
 Contours -> 10]
```

[image]

If you want two-dimensional slices:

```
GraphicsGrid[
   Partition[
   Table[
   ContourPlot[x z + y z - x y z, 
            {x, -2, 2}, 
            {y, -2, 2}],
   {z, -2, 2, .5}], 
   3]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the wonderful work .... Can you plote afunction of 3 variables could be visualized as a 2D grid of 2D contours as this https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRjO6.png

Comment: @Emad:  So PLEASE ANSWER:  What is $c$??

Comment: c representation a constant level set ...... we assume $f(x,y,z)=c$ where c is constant

Comment: @ David G. Stork  Please see this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1573755/graphing-a-function-of-4-variables?rq=1  to understand me

Answer (score 3):

This is for illustrative purposes. [`ContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html) can be used for grid of graphics and [`SliceContourPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SliceContourPlot3D.html) for a 3D visualization. Noting the link to the provided graphic does not relate to provided function, the differences in plot are expected.

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := x z + y z - x y z
cp[c_, z0_] := 
 ContourPlot[f[x, y, z0] == c, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, 
  FrameLabel -> {Row[{"c=", c, ", z=", z0}], None}, BaseStyle -> 12]
Grid[Table[cp[i, j], {j, Range[-2, 2]}, {i, Range[-2, 2]}], 
 Frame -> All, Spacings -> {2, 0}]
g[x_, y_, z_, c_] := f[x, y, z] - c
scp[c_, z0_] := 
 SliceContourPlot3D[
  g[x, y, z, c], {z == z0}, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -4, 4}, {z, -4, 4}, 
  Contours -> {0}, ContourShading -> None, ContourStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

[image]